# Angular universal is making mongo db atlas not working

Tags: angular, mongodb, mongoose, angular-universal

I have a **NodeJs** server and an Angular 7 frontend rendered with **Angular Universal**. I am hosting this server on **Heroku**.

I want to add **MongoDB** to the server, I did not link a credit card with Heroku, so I am using **MongoDb Atlas** apart from Heroku.

The problem is this: when I try to connect to it on the server which is rendering the Angular Universal Frontend, it does not work.

The problem is not with Heroku, because it occurs also in local development.
I can confirm that Mongo Atlas is working good, I could connect to it both with shell and nodejs.

I tried both the code with Angular Universal and without. The first does not work, the second works.

When I use it with universal, it's as if the connection request is blocked.

The first two imports make both MongoDB and mongoose not working

```
require('zone.js/dist/zone-node');
require('reflect-metadata');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://<user>:<pass>@<cluster>.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true`, {useNewUrlParser: true})
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Connected to MongoDB `);
    mongoose.connection.close();
    console.log('ciao');
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

This works

```
//require('zone.js/dist/zone-node');
//require('reflect-metadata');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://<user>:<pass>@<cluster>.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true`, {useNewUrlParser: true})
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Connected to MongoDB `);
    mongoose.connection.close();
    console.log('ciao');
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**EDIT:** In addition to that problem, if I start the program more than a time without waiting a lot of time, even without universal, I got this error:

```
{ MongoParseError: Multiple texts records not allowed
    at QueryReqWrap.dns.resolveTxt [as callback] (D:\Github\unitn-statistica\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\uri_parser.js:93:27)
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:199:10)
  name: 'MongoParseError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Comment: Any luck by changing the order?  first connect to the db and then do the requires?

Comment: It doesn't sound like this will be fixed anytime soon: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1043

Comment: an issue already opened for this 
 https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7838

Comment: I do not know why, there is a problem with using both mongoose (and mongo atlas) and zone.js (used by Angular) in the same server. I did just pass to firebase firestore database, but if you really want to use mongo, I suggest using two servers: one for serving the Angular site and for its frontend API and another REST API to interface with the mongo database. So when the Angular site wants some data, it asks to the frontend API wich resides in the same server of the site, the frontend API will ask the data to the database API (separate server) that will take the data from mongo and return it.